# Laravel 5.4 add a message to validator's errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So I am receiving data from a form that should reset user passwords: 
Old Password: |field| 
New Password: |field| 
Confirm Password: |field| 
And i want to be able to display a message out for the user if his old password does not match what he entered in the first field. I don't want to make an entirely new validation method and just want to throw an error to the use when i make my own if(). So how do I achieve this using the $errors variable that is available in my blade views

So here is an example of my controllers method

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'oldPassword' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed'
    ]);
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(password_verify($request->newPass,$user->password)){
         $user = User::find($user->id);
         $user->password = bcrypt($request->newPass);
         $user->save();
    }else{
         //the code for adding a new key to $errors variable
         return back(); Or return redirect('path');
    }
}
```

So in the view I want to this

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in your controller:

```
$validator =  Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'oldPassword' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed'
]);
```

And then before your `return back();`, add:

```
$validator->after(function($validator) {
    $validator->errors()->add('tagName', 'Error message');
});
```

With your message.